# RequireJS script error when requiring "ReleaseaManagement/Core/RestClient" on TFS 2015 and 2017

Tags: tfs-2015, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I'm creating an tfs hub Extension (2015/2017) and need to read the projects' release defs and create releases also. I know, I could make direkt Rest Calls instead of using the methods of the rest clients. But they seem more comfortable to me.

When I try to get the Restmanagement RestClient, I get:
Script error for: ReleaseManagement/Core/RestClient
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror

In both TFS.2015.2 and TFS.2017

Doesn't the client yet exist on-premise?

Comment: Could you please post the code snippet how you get the release definitions when you get the errors? And put the whole error messages here?

Comment: This is the whole error message in the IE debugger console, and it doesnt come to the code inside the .ts. It obviously stops the execution on the first line: "import RM_Core_RestClient = require("ReleaseManagement/Core/RestClient");"

Comment: Referenced by: //<reference path='../../node_modules/vss-web-extension-sdk/typings/rmo.d.ts' />

Comment: You refer to this document to know about  getting REST Client for Release Management.  https://github.com/Microsoft/vss-web-extension-sdk/blob/master/typings/rmo.d.ts

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this article for how to use Rest API in extension to read a release definition: [Writing a ReleaseManagement extension for cloning an existing release definition](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chandananjani/2016/05/05/writing-a-releasemanagement-extension-for-cloning-an-existing-release-definition/).

The code to read a release definition:

```
VSS.require(["VSS/Controls", "VSS/Service", "ReleaseManagement/Core/RestClient"],
var rmClient = VSS_Service.getCollectionClient(RM_WebApi.ReleaseHttpClient);
rmClient.getReleaseDefinition(vsoContext.project.id,sourceItemContext.definition.id);
```

And if you are using typescript, you need to include "ms.vss-releaseManagement-web.release-service-data-external" in the contribution like following:

```
"contributions": [
        {
            "id": "release-status",
            "type": "ms.vss-web.hub",
            "includes": [ "ms.vss-releaseManagement-web.release-service-data-external" ],
            "description": "A hub to show release status",
            "targets": [
                "ms.vss-work-web.work-hub-group"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "name": "hello",
                "order": 99,
                "uri": "app.html"
            }
        }
    ]
```

Comment: eddchen, my example is in typescript. I call "VSS.require(["scripts/app"], function () { });" and there - on top of my app.ts - I call the import/require to "ReleaseManagement/Core/RestClient" - but it stops execution when requiring this way. I can try out your way, calling it from JavaScript, but how can I pass it in to the typescript app then? (Still, the inside-typescript require should also work by design, right?)

Comment: From transpiled typescript (JavaScript): "define(["require", "exports", "VSS/Controls", "VSS/Controls/StatusIndicator", "VSS/Controls/TreeView", "VSS/Controls/Dialogs", "TFS/Core/RestClient", "TFS/VersionControl/TfvcRestClient", "TFS/Build/RestClient", "ReleaseManagement/Core/RestClient", "q"], function (require, exports, VSS_Controls, VSS_Controls_StatusIndicator, VSS_Controls_TreeView, VSS_Controls_Dialogs, TFS_Core_RestClient, TFS_VC_TfvcRestClient, TFS_Build_RestClient, RM_Core_RestClient, Q) {
"

Comment: @FerdiÖztürk Sorry for didn't check your issue carefully. It is a known issue with typescript, the workaround is including "ms.vss-releaseManagement-web.release-service-data-external" in the contribution. Refer to my updated answer for details. It works at my side with typescript, let me know if you have any issue with it. :)

Comment: thanks for the update. But it still does not work for me, same script error thrown in the console (at compatbasejs 77,742). can you ping me in skype4b? ferdi.oeztuerk.extern@itergo.com