# Error Message Appeared while Populate data in to VSTS / TFS , Build/release summary tab

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-devops-rest-api

I am running VSTS/TFS extension developed by me and trying to  display summary with data generated with extension once the Build/release completes, in build/release summary tabs .I am getting below message while trying to  display my report in VSTS/TFS , Build/release summary tab

[image: error message]

"****Extension Name Here**** **is taking longer than expected to load. Learn More about this extension, including available support options.** "

At times when I refresh my page this message get disappear and load expected data on summary tab

I have tried to find reason for this message with aid on online content but no clue found. Please be kind enough to provide some tips to get rid of this message and display data.

Comment: How many time it takes to retrieve the data?

Comment: @starain-MSFT , its just one/two second or less than it. Does it affect the obtaining data?. We are retrieving data in two methods in build summary tab from attach method and in release summary tab by reading log

Comment: What's the detail code of your extension? I just test with [build-results-enhancer extension](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-extension-samples/tree/master/build-results-enhancer)

Comment: this is how I have done it for release summary tab : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44451462/populate-data-in-to-vsts-release-summary-tab?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: What's the console logs in browser?

Comment: Hi @Eddie-MSFT , I found below error in chrome log. could this be clue?----- RestClient.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
14:86:18.458 :8080/tfs/_static/3rdParty/_scripts/requirejs-2.1.14.min.js:6 Uncaught Error: Script error for: ReleaseManagement/Core/RestClient
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
    at c (:8080/tfs/_static/3rdParty/_scripts/requirejs-2.1.14.min.js:6) --<more error details>-----

Comment: @Lalindu Same as this issue. However, the solution only works in VSTS. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43779669/requirejs-script-error-when-requiring-releaseamanagement-core-restclient-on-tf/43840354?noredirect=1#comment74770905_43840354

Answer (score 1):

This happened in some of my extensions, too.

I solved it by loading the contents of the page asynchronously. 
The initial page should load very fast. The processing of the data and following display of the results is only started when the page is loaded. When the processing is done, the contents of the page get updated. I did this by using an MVVM-like behavior with knockout.